# Color picker default behavior?

Tags: interface, workflow

Just a theoretical question here.
Why is the color wheel selector in blender white in the center? Is there any reason not to use the neutral colors that usually are in the center of the color wheel?

Comment: White isn't a neutral color? What would you expect to be there?

Comment: It's just a system that represents the color in HSV space. What exactly do you mean?

Comment: gandalf3, a neutral desaturated grey.

Comment: someonewithpc, I was pointing that comonly the midle of the circle is a neutral desaturated gray. Your coment about HSV make me think about the color space and that answered a lot of my question. Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change the color selector type in the user preferences.
To open user preferences, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> then under the *System* tab change the *Color Picker Type*. I think you may be looking for the *Circle (HSL)* type.
[image: user preferences]

Comment: Thanks for the data, I never pay atention to that particular selector in the user prefs. I was asking for HSL selector just because a theorical thing I'm trying to explain about colors :) Thankyou!!